# Google cloud Funtions consuming message from a Pubsub Topic

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am little bit confused in how the pubsub configuration will work:
Suppose that I have a single topic called XYZ. Then I create two cloud functions called CF1 and CF2. Both of them will be triggered when a message is published to XYZ topic.
Besides that I have two subscription, S1 an S2 on the XYZ topic.

I imagine that the same message will be delivery for CF1, CF2, S1 and S2, is that correct?

When will the message be deleted from topic? All the resources (CF1, CF2, S1 and S2) must ACK the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every subscription that exists, each message will be delivered to a subscriber for that subscription, yes. Cloud functions attached to topics create subscriptions, so they are no different than creating your own subscription.

If you do not enable message retention on either the topic or the subscriptions, then the message is deleted when all subscriptions have acknowledged the message or their message retention duration has passed. If you have a dead letter topic attached to a subscription a the subscribers for that subscription repeatedly do not acknowledge the message, then the message will be published to the dead letter topic and acknowledged for the original subscription on your behalf.

If you have retain acknowledge messages enabled on a subscription or message retention enabled on the topic, then messages will not be deleted until the maximum across all those time periods has passed.

Comment: I think it sould be more explicit in the documentation.